# Laravel migrations with root database user

Tags: laravel

My databases have two different users -> for the app and root - where the important part is that the app user cannot drop or alter (as an added security layer to protect my precious data)

I want to user laravel migrations, but I'm always hitting that permissions denied problem when I'm adding / removing columns or tables as it is using the default connection which is the 'app'. What is the correct way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new environment [as described here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) and configure the database as `root` for that environment. Then you should specify the configuration environment when running the artisan command with `--env` option.

```
php artisan migrate --env=something
```